# How to make a div button to link to another web page

Tags: html, button, hyperlink, contact-form-7

I am working on Contact form 7 and tryin to make the existing Submit button to link to another website. Where should I insert the link? Here is the existing code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">[submit class:btn class:btn_lg class:btn_primary class:btn_solid class:btn_lg "Submit"]</div>
</div>
```

Hopefully I will reuse the existing contact form as a banner and keep the existing style.